# Offline Lorem Ipsum Bookmarklet

Tags: bookmarklet, lorem-ipsum

I'm looking for a very simple Bookmarklet which presents me with some Lipsum text. The ones I've seen generally make requests to a generator - but I want one which I can use offline (how often does Lorum Ipsum text change..?!).

Has anyone got any suggestions? It'd be nice to be able to specify how many paragraphs I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written this [Bookmarklet](http://jsfiddle.net/BmWJ7/). I've only tested in Firefox - it's simple, but meets my requirements. I don't have a Blog, so I thought I'd share it on Stack instead!

(though, I can't post the bookmarklet itself on Stack, so please see attached fiddle...  also, the code is bodged together and not tidied up, but, it's functional for my need!)

```
.
```

Comment: Very nice job, I've used it and it works like a charm!